# iOS simulator with internet connection

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ios-simulator

I'd like to add something related to network on iOS simulator.
Situation 1:
 - My MAC(Yosemite 10.10.5) is connected to Internet by **WIFI**
 - Run Xcode then start Simulator -> Can **connect** Internet via Simulator

Situation 2:
 - My MAC(Yosemite 10.10.5) is connected to Internet by **CABLE LAN**
 - Run Xcode then start Simulator -> Can **NOT connect** Internet via Simulator

Is there anyone has some point in this problem ?
Please help me
Thank you so much !

Comment: can you notify me about the result  ?

Comment: Thank you so much, I have already resolved it

Comment: thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can solve your problem with this way :
In System Preferences / Network you can rearrange the order in which the computer gains Internet connection. Just place LAN on top of the list.
[image]